# Get Data from Linkedin public profiles in android application using v2 api

Tags: android, api, sdk, linkedin-api

I want to get public posts from linkedin profile and display it in my app. Unfortunately Linkedin doesnt support AndroidSDK anymore. It would be perfect if I dont need to login to linkedin account(I can do it when I use web ). Is that possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as they are authenticated member, becuase you need URN to make the API call, as below:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners={URN}&sharesPerOwner=100
```

Source: [Find Shares by Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#find-shares-by-owner)